# Vanishing Data Source, Placeholder, etc Fields When Rendering Parameters Template Set

Tags: datasource, rendering-parameters

In Sitecore 10.1, when I set the Parameters Template in my rendering, the Edit component properties dialog shows the expected parameters fields but all other fields, including Data Source, Placeholder, Caching etc do not show...

[image]

As soon as I set the Parameters Template value to None, they return.

[image]

What is causing this?  What needs to be done so that all fields show?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect this is because of the base template that you are using for your parameters.

Please can you verify that the parameters template that you are assigning inherits the **Standard Rendering Parameters**. If not, try switching to that base template and see if it fixes the issue.

You can find the Standard Rendering Parameters template here:

> /sitecore/templates/System/Layout/Rendering Parameters/Standard
> Rendering Parameters

Comment: Literal ‍♂️.  This was exactly the cause.  My rendering parameters extended Standard template and not Standard Rendering Parameters.  When I switched the Base template to Standard Rendering Parameters, it worked exactly as expected.  Thank you.